# Javascript rock paper Scissors game with a best 2 out of three option

Tags: javascript

I am newbie and am trying to learn how to code. I have this rockpaperscissors game i am trying to make. It is supposed to have a best out of three mode and a single mode. And I have most of the code down. But I am stuck at the choosing which mode to play part. I have the function but I have two problems: 1. If I put 1 as an option it will still run best of 3 mode and 2. even in best of 3 mode, it will run at least four times until a winner is picked and I believe it is only counting and adding the user input.
I probably have more problems than that but I believe these are my biggest roadblocks. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far...

```
var OneRound = function(){
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var botChoice = Math.random();
  if (botChoice < 0.34) {
    botChoice = "rock";
  } else if(botChoice <= 0.67) {
    botChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    botChoice = "scissors";
  } 
  //console.log("Computer chooses: " + computerChoice);
//one round mode
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        
        return "The result is a tie!" + " " + "Lets play again." ;
    }
    
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "You win!";
        }
        else {
            return "Bot wins :(";
        }
    }
    
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "You win!";
        }
        else {
            return "Bot wins :(";
        }
            
    }
    
    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "Bot wins :(";
        }
        else {
            return "You win!";
        }
    }  
    else{
       if(choice2 === "rock"){
         return "Not an option Try again."
       }
      else if (choice2 === "paper"){
        return "Not an option Try again."
      }
      else if(choice2 === "scissors"){
        return "Not an option Try again."
      }
    }
    
    } //closes compare function
  console.log("Computer chooses: " + botChoice) 
  console.log(compare(userChoice,botChoice));
}

var game = function(){
  //global scores needed 
  var userScore = 0;
  var botScore = 0;
  // what mode do you want to play?
  var pickyourpoison = prompt("pick 1 for one round or pick 2 for best two out of three");
  //if single run playerround
  if (pickyourpoison = 1){
    OneRound()
  }
  //if best of three run while loop stops when either party scores 2 
  if (pickyourpoison = 2){
    while(userScore<pickyourpoison && botScore<pickyourpoison){
      var score = OneRound();
      if(score = "You win!"){
        userScore+=1
        console.log(userScore)
      }
      else if (score = "Bot wins :(" ){
        botScore+=1
        console.log(botScore)
      }
    }
    if (userScore = 2){
      console.log("Well played")
    }
    else if (botScore = 2){
      console.log("Better luck next time")
    }
  }
}
game()
```

here is the error that comes back to me

pick 1 for one round or pick 2 for best two out of three> 2
Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?> rock
Computer chooses: scissors
You win!
Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?> rock
Computer chooses: paper
Bot wins :(
1
Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?> rock
Computer chooses: rock
The result is a tie! Lets play again.
2
Well played

Comment: You have many `if (a = b)` this is an *assignment* which will resolve to the value of `b` (and therefore in all of your cases to a truthy) ... Use `if (a === b)` for a *comparison* instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pickyourpoison` you're using a single `=` instead of `===` remember in java script = sets up a variable while === compares values. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make that edit and it did help solve the first problem. But now the second part which is the best 2 out of three option has become the main hurdle. For some reason my algo won't add 1 to the botScore but will do so for the userScore

Comment: Did you check all your `=`, doing a quick review I also saw your `if` statment inside the 
`while` statement of `choseyourpoison=2` where you use `=` instead of `===` (also check your `choseyourpoison = 2`)